# NetBeans - show compiler warnings for JSP in non-standard location

Tags: maven, jsp, netbeans, liferay, osgi

Modular components for Liferay portal provided as OSGi modules use non standard Maven layout. All JSP pages are located in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources` instead of typical `/src/main/webapps`. Moreover, `jar` packaging is used instead of typical `war`. When such a project is opened in NetBeans, no errors or warnings are shown in JSP file even it is broken deliberately.

Example project can be found here https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.1/maven/apps/jsp-portlet

Can I somehow configure NetBeans to process my JSP files as usual?

Comment: You can have dedicated IDE plugin for liferay projects using Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans [source code](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/blob/master/enterprise/maven.j2ee/src/org/netbeans/modules/maven/j2ee/web/WebProjectWebRootProvider.java) revealed there is some support for non-standard locations via the configuration of maven-war-plugin. So this plugin has to be present even not needed for the build:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```